# XML, XSLT and XSD which Framework (Java or .NET?)

Tags: java, xml, vb.net, xslt, xsd

I'd like to start a project and I'm not sure which framework would be the best for this case. Let me explain what to do:

There is a Server which Contents some Information in his database.
I can realize a XML-Export with use of some shell-commands. After 
all I get some XML-Data, I  transform this XML-Data with XSLT to
reduce the whole content to some core-content. After transforming it
I receive another (smaller) XML-Data. For Validating purposes I now use a
customized XSD.

The main question is which what Kind of technology/framework (VB?, ASP?, Java?, JSP?...) should I use. What's maybe easier?

I want to have a web interface which contains a button to trigger the 
whole sequence automatically. At the end the result should look like this:

> 1. [Server]      --xml-export-->>         [XML-Data]
> 2. [XML-Data]    --XSL-Transformation-->> [reduced XML]
> 3. [reduced XML] --parsing-XSD(validation)-->> [WebInterface]

Notice that the `[WebInterface]` should contain a button to be able to trigger
the sequences 1 - 3 everytime again and again.

Comment: Your planned use of XSLT for transformation and XSD for validation looks fine, but... *The main question is which what Kind of technology/framework (VB?, ASP?, Java?, JSP?...) should I use. What's maybe easier?* is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.   It's way too broad and is a bit too opinion-oriented.    Choose what works best based on your knowledge and your client/customer/context's requirements, and return with more specific questions.

Comment: Hey kjhughes, thanks for your Response, a Little more specific: If I use Java I think I can parse the XSD with JAXB to generate JavaCode and then I can U JSP for WEBApp... and with the JSP ActionListener I Trigger the sequence again. Is this true? But I am not sure how it works in .NET... Is just ASP enough or are there other Tools that I need for the same plan in .NET which i didn't noticed?

Comment: *...then I can use JSP...

Comment: Most XML libraries for the Java platform will have .NET counterparts, but, again, you probably ought to read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to better fit your questions to this site.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow questions asking for advice on technology selection tend to get speedily closed, with the claim that the answer is a matter of opinion. Actually, I think technology choices can be made objectively, but only with a great deal more information than one can usually include in an SO question: for example the best choice often depends on the availability of skills, and on what other applications are running in the same environment. For example, what platform does the database use?

I would use Java for this without hesitation, because I know Java; alternatively I would use Scala, because I know Scala would do the job well and I really want to learn Scala. Your own motivations and constraints (and those of your employer/client) are likely to be different.